# Return how much trimws has trimmed from a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm using trimws(x) to trim the white spaces from a dataset.

Like the output of a "find and replace" in excel, I'd like to know how much work trimws has done; specifically how much white space has been removed from the whole dataframe - mostly for my satisfaction, but also potentially then to further group the work that trimws does by other variables to see whether there's any pattern to where the white space is creeping in upstream.

Example:

```
x <- "  Some text.  "

trimws(x)
```

And then some output like:

`# trimws removed 1708 white space characters and 13 new line characters`

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. It should be fairly easy to simulate a small dataset for this.

Comment: The question has been edited accordingly

Comment: The question should be internally consistent. The output shown is inconsistent with the input.

Comment: Also the subject says the input is a data frame but the sample input is not a data frame. Please clean this all up.

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of whitespace characters removed:

```
x <- "  Some text.  "
nchar(x) - nchar(trimws(x)) # no of whitespace characters removed
## [1] 4
```

The only whitespace in the example is space but presumably the only occurrences of newline, return and tab are in the trimmed part so if these are possible too then this gives the number of spaces removed:

```
xx <- gsub("[\n\r\t]", "", x)
nchar(xx) - nchar(trimws(xx))  # no of spaces removed
```

and the difference between this and the first code snippet given above is the number of non-spaces removed.

Comment: Oh thank you, that's...kind of obvious when you put it like that!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you can modify the current code for `trimws()` (avaiable [here](https://github.com/cran/backports/blob/master/R/trimws.R)).

You just need to change `sub()` with `grep()` in order to count how many `space` char are found in `x`.

```
my_trimws = function(x, which = c("both", "left", "right")) {
  which = match.arg(which)
  mysub = function(re, x) grep(re, x, perl = TRUE)

  if (which == "left")
    n <- mysub("^[ \t\r\n]+", x)
  if (which == "right")
    n <- mysub("[ \t\r\n]+$", x)

  n <- sum(mysub("^[ \t\r\n]+", x), mysub("[ \t\r\n]+$", x))

  cat("trimws() removed ", n, " spaces\n") # prints to the console
  return(n)
}
```

Your example:

```
x <- "  Some text.  "
r <- my_trimws(x)
#trimws() removed  2  spaces
# r
# [1] 2
```